# How to Find and Decode URL Encoded Strings in Website's HTML/JavaScript for Scraping Live Odds from OddsPortal?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working on a project to scrape live odds for individual games from OddsPortal.
https://www.oddsportal.com/inplay-odds/live-now/football/
based on this helpful guide https://github.com/jckkrr/Unlayering_Oddsportal ,

My goal is to obtain live odds data for each game, but I'm encountering a challenge in accessing the necessary URLs.

Using Python's requests library, I can fetch the list of all live matches from this feed URL:
https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/livegames/liveOdds/0/0.dat?_=

```
import requests

url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/livegames/liveOdds/0/0.dat?_="
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
```

The problem arises when trying to access the live odds for each game.

The odds are contained in separate URLs with the following structure:
`https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-1-{match_id_code}-1-2-{secondary_id_code}.dat`

This is a screenshot for individual live game webpage and it's respective odds feed url https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/live-event/1-1-AsILkjnd-1-2-yjbd1.dat (when the live game end, the odds url return 404)

[image]

In this example (from the screenshot), the first id code `AsILkjnd` can be found on the list of all live matches from this feed URL: https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/livegames/liveOdds/0/0.dat?_=

but the secondary_id_code is not found there or even in the html of the individual page.

I'm currently stuck on finding and decoding the secondary_id_code.

It appears to be a URL encoded string similar to `%79%6a%39%64%39`, which I believe is hidden within the website’s HTML or JavaScript code.

So far, I've been unable to locate these encoded strings.

Can anyone help how to find and decode these URL encoded strings

Comment: All of your example URLs return 404 errors so it will be difficult for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @larsks I made a mistake in my question. the correct live games url feed is: https://www.oddsportal.com/feed/livegames/liveOdds/0/0.dat?_=

Comment: btw, from [their terms of usage](https://www.oddsportal.com/terms/):  `you are not
permitted to use our content available on the Website by embedding, aggregating,
scraping or recreating it without our express consent, unless otherwise provided for by
applicable laws and regulations`

Answer (score 1):

Since the *secondary_id_code* is not readily available, it's likely that it is dynamically loaded onto the page, possibly via JavaScript. Websites like OddsPortal often use JavaScript to load data dynamically, which means that simply fetching the page's HTML might not reveal all the data that a browser would show to a user. Here's how to tackle this:

## 1. Analyze Network Traffic

- Use your browser's Developer Tools (usually accessible by pressing *F12* or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect") and go to the "Network" tab.
- Refresh the page and watch for XHR (XMLHttpRequest) or Fetch requests that load after the initial page load. These requests often fetch dynamic content, such as your *secondary_id_code*.

## 2. Use Selenium or a Similar Tool:

- Since the *secondary_id_code* might be loaded dynamically, consider using Selenium, a tool that automates web browsers. Selenium can execute JavaScript just like a real browser, allowing you to access data that's loaded dynamically.
- Here's a simplified approach to using Selenium to access the dynamic content:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    # Path to your WebDriver (e.g., ChromeDriver)
    driver_path = '/path/to/your/chromedriver'
    
    # URL of the live matches page
    url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/inplay-odds/live-now/football/'
    
    # Initialize the WebDriver and open the URL
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
    driver.get(url)
    
    # You may need to wait for the page to load dynamically loaded content
    # For this, Selenium provides explicit and implicit waits
    
    # Now, you can search the DOM for the `secondary_id_code` as it would be rendered in a browser
    # For example, finding an element that contains the code, or observing AJAX requests that might contain it
    # This could involve analyzing the page's JavaScript or observing network requests, as mentioned earlier
    
    # Always remember to close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()
```

## 3. Decoding the *secondary_id_code*

- If you find the *secondary_id_code* but it's URL encoded (like *%79%6a%39%64%39*), you can decode it using Python's *urllib.parse.unquote()* function:

```
    from urllib.parse import unquote
    
    encoded_str = '%79%6a%39%64%39'
    decoded_str = unquote(encoded_str)
    print(decoded_str)  # This will print the decoded string
```